# Django TypeError 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, typeerror

I get an Error for the line: *username = login_form.cleaned_data('username')*, because somewhere it seems to be a dict, but I cannot understand why. Can anyone please tell me, what the problem is?

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'web/base.html')


def register_view(request):
    register_form = UserCreationForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        register_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            register_form.save()
            username = register_form.cleaned_data("username")
            password = register_form.cleaned_data("password1")
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
    return render(request, 'web/register.html', {'register_form': register_form})


def login_view(request):
    login_form = AuthenticationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            username = login_form.cleaned_data('username')
            password = login_form.cleaned_data('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)

    return render(request, 'web/login.html', {'login_form': login_form})


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect(reverse('web:index'))
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the actual error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the values from dictionary, like:

```
username = login_form.cleaned_data['username']
password = login_form.cleaned_data['password']
```

You cannot get the value of a key in DICTIONARIES using () instead use [].

Answer (score 1):

`Form.cleaned_data` is indeed a dictionary, by design. To get the value for a key in a dictionary, use `[ ]`, like

```py
username = register_form.cleaned_data["username"]
```

Here are the docs on `Form.cleaned_data`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data

Answer (score 0):

`login_form.cleaned_data` is a dictionary, so `username = login_form.cleaned_data('username')` makes no sense, you should work with:

```
username = login_form.cleaned_data['username']
password = login_form.cleaned_data['password']
```

the same will thus happen with the `password` element.